# Spring HttpInvoker: how to replace serviceUrl at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, remoting

The issue is discussed couple of times, but I was not able to find a solution that solves our problem.
    We have the following HttpInvoker service that takes the remote URL from Database:

```
@Service("exampleService")
public class ExampleHttpInvoker extends HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean {

    @Resource
    private DBService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws ConfigurationException {

       String url = service.getURL();
       this.setServiceUrl(url);
       this.setServiceInterface(RemoteInterface.class);
       this.setHttpInvokerRequestExecutor(new CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor());
            afterPropertiesSet();

     } 

   }
```

The URL can be changed between remote calls.
How to replace serviceUrl at runtime?
We can not use Session or Request scope since the service is not Web aware.
Any help will be appreciated.

Best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me how you can get the correct `DBService` based on your http request, so I suppose you know how to do that. So you can do the following:

1. Write a Filter that fetches the correct `DBService` and puts it on TLS.
2. Replace the `DBService` on `ExampleHttpInvoker` with `DBServiceWrapper` (your class) that fetches the correct `DBService` from TLS and invokes the proper methods.
3. Don't forget to clear the TLS in your Filter, once the request is done.

Comment: My clarification: I would be able to solve my problem if I would able to create the ExampleHttpInvoker before each remote call or upon DB modification. In Spring is possible to use @Scope(“request”) or @Scope(“session”), but these options are valid only in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext. I am looking for a way to recreate my ExampleHttpInvoker singleton. Even I will use TLS I do not understand how the ExampleHttpInvoker will be recreated upon the modification of the URL in TLS.

Comment: I'm afraid that if your object is singleton, you should not recreate it. Something is wrong with your design. However, you can create custom scopes with spring. May be it's the right solution for you.